# How do I bind the tree structure UI using endless JSON - Angular 8

Tags: angular, binding, treeview, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have the a JSON structure. It contains children array for each object. Some children array may have a value sometimes it doesn't.

My Question is How do I create a tree view using the following JSON:

```
this.fileList = [
  {
    "name": "New Folder1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "New Folder4",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "New File",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "New File",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "New Folder7",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "New Folder2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "File1",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "New Folder3",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "New Folder5",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "New File",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "New File",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "File1",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

And my final output should display like this on my screen. (Note: Those arraow, equals, etc.. are not mandatory. It is just your reference. I just need the tree view only without any material. I need to achieve this by using ngFor, ngIf of some other conditions including the CSS).

```
->Folder A
    =>Folder B
        --Folder C
        --Folder D
    =>Folder E
        --Folder F
->Folder G
    =>Folder H
        --Folder I
->Folder J
    =>Folder K
    =>Folder L
```

I hope you guys are understand what I want. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular You can use template reference to achieve this nested view. here is the code snippet for example:

```
<ng-template #folderTemplate let-folder>

    <-- BIND DATA OF FOLDER OBJECT-->

    <div *ngIf="folder.children" class="children-folder">
        <!-- Invoke the recursive template. -->
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="folderTemplate"
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: folder.children }">
            <!--
                HACK: The "$implicit" property of the ngFor context is what will
                be made available to the template ref's implicit let-query binding.
            -->
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="folderTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: rootFolderObject }">
</ng-template>
```

Here **rootFolderObject** will be your main dataset on each children occurence the template ref will be populated. you can iterate children nested list and bind the data inside foldetTemplate with *folder* object.

Comment: Thanks! . I integrated this code. Where do I add JSON structure? I couldn't get it. Can you please explain it. I named the structure as this.fileList.